# Input directly to a function?

Tags: c++, function, input, struct

Is there any way I can take input from the user and pass it directly to a function without parameters for the input?

I have a program that uses a structure named "Fraction" which holds 2 properties, numerator and denominator (both integers). I want to be able to do something like this:

```
fraction a;

cout << "Enter a fraction "; //User inputs something like "1/2"
read(a);   // "1/2" is read into the fraction struct a, num = 1 and den = 2
cout << "You entered ";
print(a);
cout << endl;
```

Can I do this or do I need to store the numerator and denominator in separate variables and pass them to the `read` function?

Thanks

Comment: *pass it directly to a function without parameters for the input*.. What?

Comment: So I guess that's a no

Comment: No, it just means "what?". The question is unclear.

Comment: I want to take input from a user and read it into a function

Comment: I only know how to do this by using parameters in a function call, but i'm TAing a computer science class and the professor is asking them to implement the above code. I think he might have just made a typo or something.

Comment: You could pass an `istream` object to a function and have the function read the data.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest overloading `operator >>` in your `Fraction` class.

```
class Fraction
{
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Fraction& f);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Fraction& f)
{
  // Read numerator
  input >> f.numerator;

  char slash;
  input >> slash;

  // Read the denominator
  input >> f.denominator;

  return input;
}
```

The overload will allow you to write code like:

```
Fraction f;
std::cin >> f;
```

There are many alternatives, such as having a function that reads the data:

```
void Read_Fraction(std::istream& input,
                   int& numerator,
                   int& denomenator)
{
  char slash;
  input >> numerator >> slash >> denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask about taking input from the user without a parameterized function, but your example shows you using functions with arguments for which you ask, "can I do this?" I'm not sure which approach you're asking about.

Yes, you can do what you have shown in your example, but in this case you're using functions with parameters. You need to implement `read` to use `cin` to expect the user to enter two integers through `stdin` (or else how would some arbitrary function know that you anticipate two and only two integers from the user before proceeding?).

You cannot "pass" anything to a function without parameters. What you could do is use a global variable that your `read` and `print` functions are aware of, but it is preferable to avoid globals and instead pass data around as arguments to function calls.

Edit: see Thomas's answer for an alternative to using `cin`.

Answer (score 0):

the following method should be helpful

```
class Fraction{
private:
int numerator;
unsigned int denominator;

public:
friend istream& operator>>(istream &input, Fraction &f);
};

istream& operator>>(istream &input, Fraction &f){

string x = "";
char y = x[0];
int i = 0;
input >> x;
while (y != '/' && (isdigit(y) || i == 0)) {
i++;
y = x[i];
}
 f.numerator= stoi(x.substr(0, i));
 f.denominator= stoi(x.substr(i + 1, x.length()));

 return input;
 }
```

Comment: Bad advice: std::istream itself is able to read numbers, no need for "string x".